# R aggregate rows of a data frame over multiple columns with different operators

Tags: r, aggregate

Say I have the following data frame

```
ID   A    B    C
1    10   10   10
1    20   5    15
1    30   0    12
2    10   5    13
2    0    10   10
...
```

I would like to aggregate the frame by IDs but apply `mean()` to A, `min()` to B and `max()` to C.

Resulting into this

```
ID   A    B    C
1    20   0    15
2    5    5    13
...
```

How can I do this efficiently (I have a very large data frame)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.table` approach,

```
Library("data.table")
Table1 <- data.table(df)
Table1[, list(A = mean(A), B = min(B), C = max(C)), by = "ID"]
#   ID  A B  C
#1:  1 20 0 15
#2:  2  5 5 13
```

Answer (score 3):

Use dplyr package. assuming your data frame name is "data":

```
library(dplyr)
t1 <- summarize(group_by(data,ID), A=mean(A), B=min(B), C=max(C) )
t1 <- as.data.frame(t1)
t1
```

Output :

```
  ID  A B  C
1  1 20 0 15
2  2  5 5 13
```